# Faster way to extract histogram from an image

Tags: java, image, histogram

I'm looking for a faster way to extract histogram data from an image.
I'm currently using this piece of code that needs about 1200ms for a 6mpx JPEG image:

```
        ImageReader imageReader = (ImageReader) iter.next();
        imageReader.setInput(is);
        BufferedImage image = imageReader.read(0);
        int height = image.getHeight();
        int width = image.getWidth();
        Raster raster = image.getRaster();
        int[][] bins = new int[3][256];

        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) 
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
                bins[0][raster.getSample(i, j, 0)]++;
                bins[1][raster.getSample(i, j, 1)]++;
                bins[2][raster.getSample(i, j, 2)]++;

            }
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Depending on how accurate the result needs to be, you could take a sub-sample and extrapolate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're doing a *lot* of *getSamples* method calls and they're in turn doing calls and calls etc.

I work often with pictures and *the* typical trick to gain speed is to manipulate directly the underlying *int[]* (in this case your BufferedImage must be backed by an int[]).

The difference between accessing the *int[]* and doing, say, a *getRGB* can be gigantic.  When I write gigantic, I mean by as much as two orders of magnitude (try doing a *getRGB* on OS X 10.4 vs *int[x]* and you'll see the perf gain).

Also, there's no call three times *getSamples*.  I'd simply retrieve one int corresponding to your ARGB pixel and then bitshift to get the RGB bands (you're doing one histogram per R, G and B component right?).

You can gain access to the pixels array by doing something like this:

```
final int[] a = ((DataBufferInt) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
```

Also you can do what you want to do with a single loop, looping over all the pixels.

Instead of:

```
for ( int x = 0; x < width; x++ ) {
    for ( int y = 0; y < height; y++ ) {
        ....
```

You can do:

```
for ( int p = 0; p < width*height; p++ ) {
```

Now if you want to get into weirder optimizations, not as likely to prove effective you could:

- use loop unrolling (iterating over 6 million pixels is one of the rare case where it may help)
- invert the loop:  for ( p = width*height - 1; p >= 0; p--)

Answer (score 1):

You can use getSamples(int x, int y, int w, int h, int b, double[] dArray) method
It's possible that this method have internal optimisations.
Also, you can try to swap width and height.

```
for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) 
   for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
   }
}
```

And

```
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) 
   for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
   }
}
```

Between this two variants performance difference will be huge.
This is influence of the cpu cache

Comment: you sure about the swapping? What if the image is vertical, not horizontal?

Comment: you assume all the images are horizontal.